# angular translate dynamic list of objects into angular translated string with ui-srefs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translate, angular-translate

My first question on stackoverflow.

I have a problem where I have a list of objects with properties id and number and I want to make that into a list inside a angular translated text string with ui-sref tags.

Lets say the list contains the following.

```
var list = [{ id: 1, number: 34 }, { id: 2, number: 72 }, { id: 3, number: 109 }];
```

Now what I want is the following string:

```
You have successfully created issue number <a ui-sref="details({id: 1})">34</a>, <a ui-sref="details({id: 2})">72</a> and <a ui-sref="details({id: 2})">109</a>.
```

I know I in the html can have `<span translate="key" translate-value-list="list"></span>` but how do I continue from there. How should the value for this key look like?

And yes, the list is dynamical so it can contain a variable amount of objects.